# What is the order of this kernel function?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, integral

Suppose we have kernel function $K\left(t\right)=\frac{35}{32}\left(1-t^2\right)^3\mathbf{1}\left(|t|\leq 1\right)$. What is the minimal positive integer $r$ such that $\int K(t)t^rdt\neq0$?(this minimal positive integer $r$ is the order of the kernel.) It's easy to see that $\int K(t)tdt=0$, but integration $\int K(t)t^rdt$ for $r>1$ seems difficult to compute. Any ideas on how to compute them so that we can pin down the order of the kernel? Thanks!

Comment: Because $K$ is a symmetric even function, the integral is strictly positive for all even $r$ and zero for all odd $r.$  In light of this, it looks like your definition of the "order" might be incorrect.  Indeed, it conflicts with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_a_kernel)--check it out and fix your question accordingly.

Comment: @whuber You are right. Thanks! And the problem is solved too, i.e., it's a second order kernel.

Comment: @whuber There seems to be two versions of definitions for this order that differ by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of kernel order found in
"Choice of Kernel Order in Density Estimation"
Peter Hall and J. S. Marron
The Annals of Statistics
Vol. 16, No. 1 (Mar., 1988), pp. 161-173

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2241429?seq=1

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{35}{32}(1-t^2)^3dt=1
$$

With $r=1$:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{35}{32}(1-t^2)^3t^1=0 \quad \text{(odd function)}
$$

$r=2$ is the smallest integer for which the integral is different from 0:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{35}{32}(1-t^2)^3t^2=1/9 \quad \text{(even function)}
$$

(The integral can be easily calculated expanding the polynomial).

Thus, the order is $r=2$.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.